# php file writing problem

Tags: php, linux, fedora, fwrite, fputs

I have a script which constanly append strings into a file.

For example (this is a test script):

```
$i = 1;
$file = 'wikipedia/test.txt';
$text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
while($i!=0)
{
  file_put_contents($file, $text, FILE_APPEND );
}
```

But for an unknown reason my program stops appending strings when the text file reached the file size of 2097156 B . It wasn't a disk space issue since i could still create another text file yet limited to the same exact file size value.

I tried using other php functions fwrite, fputs but still didn't work out.

Any idea why this problem occurs?

Comment: Please expand on "still didn't work out." Did you encounter exactly the same problem at exactly the same file size when using `fwrite` and `fputs`?

Comment: Yes.. same problem. It stops appending when it reached the said file size

Answer (score 1):

Seems unlikely, but you might have run up against PHP's `max_execution_time` if its current setting is very low.  Try increasing its value in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesnt make sense. It never changes $i.
Try it without the while.

```
$file = 'wikipedia/test.txt';
$text = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
file_put_contents($file, $text, FILE_APPEND );
```

Comment: An unbound loop makes sense if he wants to `constantly append strings`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues that could cause this problem.

1. You may have encountered the max execution time limit ( default: 30 seconds ).
2. You may have exhausted the memory limit ( default: varies by version)
3. Something may have changed on disk ( the file permissions may have changed, or you may have exceeded a disk quota).

PHP's error output would be invaluable for identify which of these issues may have contributed to the problem.